# I need to push any view controller in between the navigation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to go to any view controller from App Delegate on notification click Like normal push.
Can anyone help me ?
Thanks

Comment: If I put as much effort in this comment as you did in this question then I would start with doin

Comment: sure I would like to know if you have a exact ans, thanks @Xorifelse

Answer (score 1):

`STSampleviewController *listview = [[STSampleviewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"STSampleviewController" bundle:nil];

 [self.navigationController pushViewController:listview animated:YES];`
 i used normal way to push viewcontroller from appdelegate

Comment: But I need to go any VC between the navigation stack.

Comment: change you condition based on your notification title or sometime

Comment: yes I got a title from the notif, When I would pass the data to any desired VC thats the issue.

Comment: what issue you have to face? share the reason of crash

Comment: `-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
    completionHandler();
    NSDictionary *userInfo=response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",userInfo);
    
    

    
    [self handlePushDataFromNotification:userInfo];
    
}
-(void)handlePushDataFromNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo{        
     } `

Comment: Example : In Navigation I have VC 1,2,3,4. Now I wana go with VC 3 and came back with the same navigation stack.

Comment: if you click back button u have to get crash .right?